# How to select different columns from each row in nd-array in Python/numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

Suppose I have 3 x 2 matrix

```
A = np.arange(3*2).reshape(3,2)
```

and wish to select elements by index array

```
I = [0, 1, 0]
```

to get

```
[[0],[3],[4]]
```

How would I do this?

Writing this way

```
A[:,[0,1,0]]
```

gives something completely different (what?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you can do is pass an **iterable** of the first dimesion value, and an **iterable** (e.g. a list) of the second dimension. Something like:

```
I = [0, 1, 0]
A[range(len(I)),I]
```

This produces:

```
>>> A[range(len(I)),I]
array([0, 3, 4])
```

In case you want it as a 2d array, you can use an additional reshape:

```
>>> A[range(len(I)),I].reshape(-1,1)
array([[0],
       [3],
       [4]])
```

> ```
> A[:,[0,1,0]]
> ```
>
> gives something completely different (what?)

It creates a matrix where the *first* column is the first (`0`) column of `A`, the *second* column is the second (`1`) column of `A`, and the third column is again the first (`0`) column of `A`.

Comment: I there any function in `numpy` with aggregation sematics like `min`, `max` and etc?

Comment: `np.min`, `np.max`, etc.

Comment: yes, but doing select, like `np.select(A, I, axis=1, keepdims=True)`?

Comment: AFAIK not, `np.choose` is probably the closest, but it works on the first dimension, so you can transpose first, and then do the processing.